# Difficulty in inserting newline character into Python string after conversion from list form

Tags: python, string

The code I'm working on takes an input, and is meant to return a "staircase" of hashes and spaces. For instance, if the input was 5, the result should be:

```
    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####
```

I've turned the input into a list of spaces and hashes, and then converted that to a string form, in order to insert \n in every space corresponding to the length of the input (e.g. every 5 characters above). However, my code prints the result in one line. Where am I going wrong??

```
x = input()
list = []
a = x-1
while a > -1:
    for i in range(0, a):
        list.append(" ")
    for i in range(0, (x-a)):
        list.append("#")
    a = a - 1
    continue

z = str("".join(list))

t = 0
while t<x:
    z = z[t:] + "\n" + z[:t]
    t = t + x
    continue


print str(z)
```

Comment: Why not insert the newlines in the first loop instead?

Comment: Don't name your variable `list`, by the way - that masks the built-in function `list()`.

Comment: You don't need to use `continue` at the end of `while` loop. You'd only use that if you wanted to skip the rest of the loop (usually in a condition or exception handler).

Comment: The algorithm you're using is basically writing C in Python, making no use of powerful features like easy string multiplication and concatenation. This script could be accomplished in just a few lines.

Comment: Take a look of Python [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html). You could use character padding to this quite easily as TigerhawkT3 mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with pseudocode, carefully laying out in clear English what you want the program to do.

1. Get a number from the user.
2. Go through each number from 1 until the user's number, inclusive.
3. On each line, print a certain number of spaces, starting from one fewer than the user's number and going down to zero, inclusive.
4. On each line, also print a certain number of hash symbols, starting from one and going up to the user's number, inclusive.

Now you can turn that into Python.

First, get a number from the user. It looks like you're using Python 2, so you could use `input()` or try the safer `raw_input()` and cast that to `int()`.

```
num = input()
```

Going through each number from one until the user's number, inclusive, means a `for` loop over a `range`. On Python 2, using `xrange()` is better practice.

```
for i in xrange(1, num+1):
```

This next part will combine steps 3 and 4, using string multiplication and concatenation. For the spaces, we need a number equal to the max number of lines minus the current line number. For the hash symbols, we just need the current line number. You can multiply a string to repeat it, such as `'hi' * 2` for `'hihi'`. Finally, the newline is taken care of automatically as the default end character in a Python 2 `print` statement.

```
    print ' ' * (num-i) + '#' * i
```

Put it all together and it looks like this:

```
num = input()
for i in xrange(1, num+1):
    print ' ' * (num-i) + '#' * i
```

As you discovered, achieving the same effect with an intricate structure of counters, nested loops, `list` operations, and slicing is more difficult to debug. The problems don't stop when you get it working properly, either - such code is difficult to maintain as well, which is a pain if you ever want to modify the program. Take a look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html) for some great examples of clear, concise Python code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
x = input()
list1 = []
a = x-1
while a > -1:
    for i in range(0, a):
        list1.append(" ")
    for i in range(0, (x-a)):
        list1.append("#")
    a = a - 1
    list1.append("\n")
    continue

z = str("".join(list1))
print z
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining that code dump, and perhaps fixing some of the issues you migrated from the OP's code, such as the `list` mask and the unnecessary string cast and `continue`?